# SELECT Primary key that refers to Foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I write a query that compares a primary key to a foreign key to see if they refer to the same record? I was thinking something like:

`SELECT BookID from books WHERE BookID = Publisher`, but obviously that's not working since they're different numbers.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
  `BookID` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `Pages` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Description` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `Publisher` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BookID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`Publisher`) REFERENCES `publisher_id`(`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: What you are asking is One to Many  (one publisher can have many books) .. not sure what your exact ask is.

Comment: Sample data and a desired result might be fun

Comment: Obviously, an ID cannot equal a string. Why does that foreign key `Publisher` use a varchar field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FOREIGN KEY (`Publisher`) REFERENCES `publisher_id`(`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

This line in your code means that there is another table called publisher_id in this database having a column named ID. Is that correct?

In normal scenarios, you name your table for eg: Publisher. Let ID be the primary key column of the Publisher table. It can contain more columns such as name, address etc.

Assuming one book has one publisher and one publisher can publish many books,
In the books table have a column called publisher_id. Then you can reference it as a foreign key as follows (have it in the create statement just like you have done above).

```
FOREIGN KEY (`publisher_id`) REFERENCES `Publisher`(`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

If you have a publisher ID with you (for eg: 5) and want to get all the book id(s) published by this publisher, you can run the following query.

```
SELECT Books.BookID FROM Books WHERE Books.publisher_id = 5;
```

*table_name*.*column_name* is the syntax for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a publisher's unique id or name (Whatever is the primary key in the publisher table) column in the book's tables as foreign keys. Book has only one publisher in most cases. Publisher can publish multiple books.

Comment: Yeah, I was in a haste. What if we know that the Publisher_id is 5 and want to match it to the BookId? Could we query like this: SELECT BookID From Books WHERE Publisher_id.Publisher = 5?

Comment: @DanSebastian yeah, you can. As long as the Books table has a publisher id column.

Answer (score 0):

May be this from what I understood:

```
SELECT BookID 
From Books
WHERE BookId.Book = Publisher_Id.Publisher
```

Comment: Will this work? Will that specific book be retrieved if its publisher's id (foreign key) matches the book's id (primary key)?

Comment: Whatever, the logic is you have to compare two columns in different tables. So the condition you should write is the first column name then dot then the table name, after that, sign = , then again second column name dot table name.

Comment: Can I write it like this? SELECT BookID From Books WHERE Publisher_id.Publisher = 5?

Comment: Yes, you can. But it will be empty! 
You need to display values that available in two tables, your condition have only one table.

Comment: I need to display values only from the Books table, but based on the BookId that is linked the Publisher_id 5. Why will it be empty if the table is populated?

Comment: Here another solution

```
SELECT BookID 
From Books
WHERE (BookId.Book = ( SELECT Publisher_Id FORM Publisher WHERE Publisher_Id = 5));
```